# Luego de recargar la página ya guardada en localStorage, los botones simplemente no funcionan

Tags: javascript, html

Mi programa funciona bien y los botones funcionan correctamente antes de recargar la página, pero luego de recargar la página ya guardada en localStorage, los botones simplemente no funcionan y no encuentro una manera de hacerlos funcionar: por más que he intentado soluciones ninguna me deja. Acá abajo les dejo los codigos de javascript y de html.

```js
const form = document.querySelector('#section-form');
const input = document.querySelector('#input-text');
const lista = document.querySelector('#tasks');


form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const tarea = input.value;

    if (!tarea) {
        alert("Por favor introduce una nota")
        return;
    }
    const lista_el = document.createElement("div");
    lista_el.classList.add("task");

    const lista_contenido_el = document.createElement("div");
    lista_contenido_el.classList.add("contenido");

    lista_el.appendChild(lista_contenido_el);


    const lista_input_el = document.createElement("input");
    lista_input_el.classList.add("text");
    lista_input_el.type = "text";
    lista_input_el.setAttribute('value', input.value)
    lista_input_el.setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");

    lista_contenido_el.appendChild(lista_input_el);

    localStorage.setItem('lista', lista.innerHTML)


    const lista_acciones_el = document.createElement("div");
    lista_acciones_el.classList.add("acciones");

    const lista_editar_el = document.createElement("button");
    lista_editar_el.classList.add("editar");
    lista_editar_el.innerHTML = "Editar";

    const lista_eliminar_el = document.createElement("button");
    lista_eliminar_el.classList.add("eliminar");
    lista_eliminar_el.innerHTML = "Eliminar";



    lista_acciones_el.appendChild(lista_editar_el);

    lista_acciones_el.appendChild(lista_eliminar_el);

    lista_el.appendChild(lista_acciones_el);

    lista.appendChild(lista_el);

    input.value = '';


    lista.addEventListener('click', e => {
        if (lista_editar_el.innerHTML.toLowerCase() == "editar") {
            lista_input_el.removeAttribute("readonly");
            lista_input_el.focus();
            lista_editar_el.innerHTML = "Salvar";
        } else {
            lista_input_el.setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
            lista_editar_el.innerHTML = "Editar";
        }
    })
    localStorage.setItem('lista', lista.innerHTML)



    lista_eliminar_el.addEventListener('click', e => {
        lista.removeChild(lista_el);
    })
    localStorage.setItem('lista', lista.innerHTML)

})


lista.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('lista');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
    <title>ToDo list</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section id="titulo" >
        <div id="section-contenedor" >
            <h1 id="sectionTitulo">Notas</h1>
            
            <!-- formulario -->
            <div id="section-contendor-2">
                <form id="section-form" >
                    <input type="text" id="input-text" placeholder="Agrega una nota... " >
                    <button type="submit" id="boton-1"> Crear nota</button>
                 </form>
            </div>
        </section>
            </div>
            <h2>Notas</h2>
            <section class="task-list">

                <div id="tasks">

                    <!-- <div class="task">
                        <div class="contenido">
                            <input type="text" class="text" value="tarea 1" readonly>
                        </div>
                        <div class="acciones">
                            <button class="editar">Editar</button>
                            <button class="eliminar">Eliminar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div> -->
                </div>
            </section>

<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```